# How to fire a function at specific time in the future in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

Example: I have `200 000 users` which have to be charged at `30 day` after registration. They all have different registration date. So the date of charging will be different for every user.

After googling I found this library [Node Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which can fire a function at a specific time. I setting the payment date for every user in a registration moment. For example, user registered at `17:36` so his payment date will be at `17:36 after 30 days`.

With `node-schedule` the code looks like this:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob(chargingDateFromDB, () => {
  console.log('The payment is done and new date for charging is set);
});
```

In this way, I believe, node will store the information about every schedule in operation memory and will keep it for `30 days` and after payment for next `30 days` and so on...

So I have doubts because of performance. Is there a better way to implement monthly subscription? Is my way of charging users is comonlly use or there have to be more efficient way?

Comment: Why would you bill different users at differnt *times* during the day? Usually systems just do a batch bill for the day - an event runs at, say, 6:00 in the morning, looks up everybody who has to pay that day and then bills them. Very often the payment date is even set, so you might be paying on, say, the 1st of the month every time but subscriptions like Google Music do actually make you pay on the day you subscribed. At any rate, I've not heard of a system that schedules individual payments for each user.

Comment: So the plan may be like this: Every morning check for paymentDate of every user and if paymentDate < currentDate => makePayment(). Something like that?

Comment: Well, you'd do something like `paymentDate = todayDate`. You'd basically be trying to check if the payment date is, say, the 21st and today is the 21st, then make the payment. You'll have to be careful with end of month dates and February, of course but make a judgement call when to process them and normalise it. Although if you want EXACTLY 30 days, not do monthly payments, then you'd have to check `(today - lastPaymentDate) = 30` in some fashion but it alleviates your end of month handling problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let ONE schedule run daily, select users who needs to be charged, and charge.

Comment: Check my comment for vlaz. It sounds like your answer.

Comment: well, yes. seems like we wrote at same instant... your question was about scheduling billings => best practice is to use a single schedule and do all billings of the day in one go. "billing" is just an example here.

Comment: PS: and yes, you will need to invest some thoughts on how to "select users to be charged" => the ones whose last charge is more than 30 days ago, for example. will depend on your payment plan